# Can I encourage g++ to inline a switch returning a sign?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I have a bunch of code like the following:

```
int sign(MyEnum e)
{
  switch(e)
  {
    case A:
    case B:
      return 1;
    case C:
    case D:
      return -1;
    default:
      throw std::runtime_error("Invalid enum value");
  }
}

int f(int a, int b, int c, MyEnum e)
{
  const int sign = sign(e);

  const int x = a * b - sign * c;
  const int y = a + sign * c;

  return x / y;
}
```

The arithmetic here is just an example.  The actual code is more complex, but the point is that `sign` is either -1 or 1 depending on an enum value, and we do a bunch of calculations where various things are multiplied by `sign`.  (**Edit**: the enum value is not known at compile time.)

I'd like this code to be optimized as though I'd written something like the following:

```
  int f(int a, int b, int c, MyEnum e)
  {
    switch(e)
    {
      case A:
      case B:
        {
          const int x = a * b - c;
          const int y = a + c;

          return x / y;
        }
      case C:
      case D:
        {
          const int x = a * b + c;
          const int y = a - c;

          return x / y;
        }
      default:
        throw new std::runtime_error("Invalid enum value");
    }
  }
```

Of course I don't actually want to *write* all the code like that, because it's a testing and maintenance nightmare.

Playing around with Compiler Explorer, it looks like the exception in `sign` may be the issue here; if I have the "default" case return, say, -1, then I get what I want.  But I would like *some* safety here.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a fundamental reason that throwing an exception prevents (or discourages the compiler from using) this optimization?
2. It looks like compiling this at `-O3` makes two clones of the method, one of which does what I want, although I don't know which one actually would get run.  Can I give hints for this?
3. I don't know if I want to compile *everything* at `-O3`.  Can I turn on optimizations for just a particular block of code, or encourage the compiler to make them?
4. Is there some fancy template metaprogramming trick or something I can use to write code that looks like the first block but which generates code looking like the second block?
5. Any other suggestions for what I'm trying to do?

**EDIT:** Since I (obviously) don't understand all the issues at hand I probably didn't give this a great title.  Please feel free to edit if you know what you're doing.

Comment: If you don't mind a GCC specific solution, then you could consider `__attribute__((always_inline))`, maybe..

Comment: Is `int sign(MyEnum)` function used by other translation units?  If it is, it needs to be available to be linked against.  If it is not, it could be in an anonymous namespace or marked `static`.

Comment: Do you know what the value of `e` will be at compile time?

Comment: About point 3: there is GCC- specifc `__attribute__((hot))`.

Comment: In this context, `static` means that the function is local to the translation unit, and does not link outside of this translation unit.  That allows the optimizers to perform more optimizations and possibly eliminate the function entirely (assuming optimization is enabled).

Comment: As a general comment, the logic of function `f` being dependent on a parameter makes `f` give off a ["logical cohesion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)#Logical) code smell. It'd probably be best to instead have a function that gets the corrected value to pass to `f`. E.g. `int i = f(a, b, corrected_c(c, e));` This would also avoid needing multiplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since in this situation, `int sign(MyEnum)` function it not used by other translation units, then it could be marked `static`.

In this context, `static` means that the function is local to the translation unit, and does not link outside of this translation unit.  (The keyword `static` has different meanings in C++ depending on the context it is used.)

That allows the optimizers to perform more optimizations and possibly eliminate the function entirely (assuming optimization is enabled).

Comment: When optimizing `f`, it doesn't matter whether `sign` is static or not, the compiler has the same optimizing possibilities (regarding `f`). Of course, if `sign` is inlined to `f`, then it can be removed.

Comment: @geza • yes, agreed.  If marked `static` the compiler doesn't have to emit the unused standalone function that may be linked against by other translation units at link time.  (When then could be LTO or WPO away.  Or dead code stripped, if not linked against.  But that's another story.  In the meantime, the OP's object file has it sitting there.)

Comment: @geza: For non-small functions, compilers will still inline them if there's only one call site *and* they're `static` so no standalone definition is needed.  i.e. they're still only one copy of the code, inside another function instead of stand-alone.  So yes, adding `static` isn't what makes inlining *possible*, but it can make the difference in getting a compiler's heuristics to actually choose to do it.

Answer (score 9):

Here's an alternative take on the thing:

```
template <int sign>
int f(int a, int b, int c)
{
  const int x = a * b - sign * c;
  const int y = a + sign * c;

  return x / y;
}


int f(int a, int b, int c, MyEnum e)
{
  const int sign = sign(e);
  if (sign == 1) return f<1>(a, b, c);
  else return f<-1>(a, b, c);
}
```

This way, you keep the safety you want (in the form of the exception), but then transform the resulting information into a compile-time value which the compiler can use for optimisations.

As [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7433673/chris) pointed out in comments, if `sign` is only ever used to switch the sign of `c`, you can get rid of the template altogether and just flip `c`'s sign when calling:

```
int f(int a, int b, int c)
{
  const int x = a * b - c;
  const int y = a + c;

  return x / y;
}


int f(int a, int b, int c, MyEnum e)
{
  const int sign = sign(e);
  if (sign == 1) return f(a, b, c);
  else return f(a, b, -c);
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the template argument here? Can't you just negate the parameter when it's passed in to f?

Comment: @Chris Sure, if the sign is only ever used to switch the sign of `c`, indeed. However, what I posted is general, and since "The actual code is more complex", I wanted to provide a general solution. Nevertheless, I will add a note to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want the compiler to inline the behavior, it's assumed that you know the value of the enum at compile-time. In such a case you can use template specialization to use the desired logic based on the value of your enum.

```cpp
int f(int a, int b, int c)
{
  const int x = a * b - c;
  const int y = a + c;
 
  return x / y;
}
 
enum MyEnum
{
    A, B, C, D
};
 
// Template definition with default behavior.
template<MyEnum e> int correct_c(int c)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid enum value");
    return 0;
};

// Specialized templates according to the value of e.
template<> int correct_c<A>(int c) { return c; }
template<> int correct_c<B>(int c) { return c; }
template<> int correct_c<C>(int c) { return -c; }
template<> int correct_c<D>(int c) { return -c; }
```

Usage:

```cpp
void test()
{
    int rA = f(7, 2, correct_c<A>(3));
    int rB = f(7, 2, correct_c<B>(3));
    int rC = f(7, 2, correct_c<C>(3));
    int rD = f(7, 2, correct_c<D>(3));
    int rUnknown = 0;
 
    try {
        rUnknown = f(7, 2, correct_c<static_cast<MyEnum>(4)>(3));
    } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
        cout << "Runtime error caught \"" << e.what() << "\"\n";
    }
 
     cout << "Results: \n"
        "rA: " << rA << "\n"
        "rB: " << rB << "\n"
        "rC: " << rC << "\n"
        "rD: " << rD << "\n"
        "rUnknown: " << rUnknown << '\n';
}
```

(Note I moved the logic for handling `c`'s dependency on `e` outside of `f` to avoid [logical cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)#Logical).)

The compiler will inline the calls to `correct_c`.

This will also prevent compiling non-enum values unless you explicitly cast them.

In the case that you need to support runtime evaluation of `e`, you can write a specific function that takes a `MyEnum` value as an argument instead of a template argument and routes it to the appropriate specialized template function.

```cpp
int correct_c(int c, MyEnum e)
{
    switch (e)
    {
        case A: return correct_c<A>(c);
        case B: return correct_c<B>(c);
        case C: return correct_c<C>(c);
        case D: return correct_c<D>(c);
        default: throw std::runtime_error("Invalid enum value");
    }
}
```